How does one prove the existence of uncountable sets in Positive Set Theory?
I've read that the usual proof of Cantor's theorem doesn't go through in Positive Set Theory because it relies on an instance of comprehension which is not positive. Does this mean that Positive Set Theory is unable to make the distinction between countable and uncountable sets? Or is there another way to establish this distinction that doesn't require Cantor's theorem or negation?
